# How to read i2c lis3dh register value with 12 bits?

Tags: c, linux, i2c

I need to read i2c register value (12 bits) of LIS3DH accelerometer. I developed this code for this, but I get always duplicated value.

```
void read_register(int filedesc,uint8_t register_address, uint16_t* register_value)
{
    uint8_t str[2] = {0};

    if (write(filedesc, &register_address, 1) == 1)
    {
        if (read(filedesc, str, 2) == 2)
        {
            *register_value = (((uint16_t)str[1])<<8) | ((uint16_t)str[0]);
           printf("register value = 0x%04X", *register_value)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        perror("error");
    }
}
```

When I execute my program I get duplicated values for example

register value = 0x30**30**

register value = 0x5D**5D**

I want to read using this function values of x, y and z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a line in your function :

```
register_address |= 0x80;
```

From the LIS3DH datasheet :

> ... a 8-bit sub-address (SUB) is transmitted: the 7 LSb
>   represent the actual register address while the MSB enables address auto increment. If the
>   MSb of the SUB field is ‘1’, the SUB (register address) is automatically increased to allow
>   multiple data read/write.

Without setting the MSB, you will just keep reading the same register in the chip, which is one byte. In other words, since you don't add the auto-increment bit, the address is not incremented, and the address read will always be the low part of the value, since the high part is in the next register (one address higher). One thing is that you can also read the 3 registers (6 bytes) in one go like this, because the x,y,z registers are contiguous.

Also, you can directly do `read(filedesc, register_value, 2)`, since the registers are in little endian (the first is the low). Same for 3 registers in one go, the only difference is that you pass an `uint16_t[3]` as parameters, and read 6 instead of 2.

Comment: I add `register_address |= 0x80;` before `if (write(filedesc, &register_address, 1) == 1) `?

Comment: @linuxcdeveloper Yes wherever you want, but before using `register_address`.

Comment: can you explain more? I don't understand why I should add it, it changes register address, Note - I use little endian model

Answer (score 0):

The fault must lie elsewhere, because when I run this program which duplicates your types and actions, it works perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define uint8_t unsigned char
#define uint16_t unsigned short

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint8_t str[2] = { 0x12, 0x34 };
    uint16_t reg, *register_value = &reg;

    *register_value = (((uint16_t)str[1])<<8) | ((uint16_t)str[0]);
    printf("register value = 0x%04X", *register_value);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
register value = 0x3412
```